# PHP load dynamic library http.so

Tags: php, rhel7

I'm trying to get a newer version of PHP installed on my RHEL7 server and get an error when it tries to start php. I've dug other similar posts but havent found one that seems to match this issue.  The RHEL7 server is currently using PHP 5.5.38 which is working (installed in /sbin/ for some reason). When I installed 7.4 it went to the normal /bin location.

In the below error the http.so does exist in that directory. The libbrotlicommon.so.1 isnt in that location but is in /opt/rh/jbcs-httpd24/root/usr/lib64/.
I'm not sure where the doubled up http.so.so comes from or where it is trying to load ssh2 twice.

Any idea what is going wrong?

```
# /bin/php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'http.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/http.so (libbrotlicommon.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/http.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/http.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'ssh2' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.4.33 (cli) (built: Dec 12 2023 14:45:16) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.33, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: PHP installed in /sbin is really weird. I'd reinstall the whole machine, to be honest. If possible, convert it to a VM so you can have both installations running in parallel.